# soap xml to JS variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, soap, xml-parsing

with postman i get the response from a wsdl url, i get the soap response all good, now i need to use data on a website so i can compare the data that the user will input with the response i got, I manage to get the response on my webpage with php-curl

```
 <?php
 $curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
 CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/numberconversion.wso?WSDL=",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
 CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
 CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>   "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" 
      xmlns:web=\"http://www.dataaccess.com/webservicesserver/\">\n   
  <soapenv:Header/>\n   
  <soapenv:Body>\n      
        <web:NumberToWords>\n         
          <ubiNum>100</ubiNum>\n      
        </web:NumberToWords>\n   
  </soapenv:Body>\n
    </soapenv:Envelope>",
 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("content-type: text/xml"),
 ));

   $response = curl_exec($curl);
     $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

   if ($err) {
     echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
 } else {
  echo $response;
}

 ?>
```

the output

```
     <soap-env:envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:header>
 <soap-env:body>
  <n0:zfi_mf_ws_consulta_clienteresponse xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:rfc:functions">
  <e_datos>
    <kunnrdf>123</kunnr>
    <name1>name</name1>
<land1>VE</land1>
   <stras>street</stras>
   <ort01>SAN FRANCISCO</ort01>
   <telf1>0261-215012</telf1>
   <stcd1>J-0701721725-7</stcd1>
     <stcd1_sg>J07017252252177</stcd1_sg>
 <smtp_addr>test@hotmail.com</smtp_addr>
<tatyp_1>Flete</tatyp_1>
    <taxkd_1>0</taxkd_1>
   <tatyp_2> Producto</tatyp_2>
<taxkd_2>1</taxkd_2>
  </e_datos>
  <e_respuesta>
  <tipo>
  <clase>
   <nro>000</nro>
  <mensaje></mensaje>
</clase>
</tipo>
  </e_respuesta>
  </n0:zfi_mf_ws_consulta_clienteresponse></soap-env:body>
</soap-env:header>
</soap-env:envelope>
```

how to get  value only, then use it to compare with another data to see if it maches, plus i need all the rest to use for another usage (put in a input field with js)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the string to XML and afterwards search by TagName, here's an example where I get a list of Movie-objects.

```
var doc;
var parser = new DOMParser();  
doc = parser.parseFromString(responseXML.data, 'text/xml');

var x = doc.getElementsByTagName("d4p1:Movie");
var movies = [];
for (var i= 0;i < x.length; i++)  
    { 
    movies.push({
        id: x[i].getElementsByTagName("d4p1:Id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
        title: x[i].getElementsByTagName("d4p1:Title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
        overview: x[i].getElementsByTagName("d4p1:Overview")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue,
        src: x[i].getElementsByTagName("d4p1:Poster")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
    });
```

Comment: thanks for answering, but i get an error Uncaught ReferenceError: responseXML is not defined, there is an html file that i have where there is post method with an input field, the user enter a number then get the response, which is either data or a message saying no data was found. plus reading the script what "d4p1:Movie" stands for, would it be for me "e_datos:kunnrdf"

Comment: The responseXML I'm using here is the response I get from my POST to the Soap API. I'm not familiar with the syntax you're using but I guess it would be the same as $response?
You would have to do something along the lines of
`var x = doc.getElementsByTagName("e_datos");
var kunnrdf = x[0].getElementsByTagName("kunnrdf");
var name1 = x[0].getElementsByTagName("name1");`